# A second formula for the dimension of the symmetric tensor product? ... (No)

Tags: combinatorics, symmetric-polynomials, combinatorial-proofs

A naive counting of the cardinal of following basis of $\operatorname{Sym}^n(V)$ (cf. the [original question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3510208/92038) for the notation and then [link](http://math.mit.edu/classes/18.952/spring2011/chapter1.pdf) p.33 in [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2181811/92038))
$$ \Big\lbrace S(e_{i_1}\otimes \cdots \otimes e_{i_n}),\ 1\leq i_1 \leq i_2 \leq \cdots \leq i_n \leq d \Big\rbrace \tag{1} \label{1}$$
yields the following formula (for  the first equality cf. for example [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2270285/finding-the-dimension-of-the-space-of-symmetric-r-tensors) or below)
$$\operatorname{dim}\big(\operatorname{Sym}^n(V) \big) = { d+n-1 \choose n} \stackrel{??}{=}\sum_{k=1}^{\min(d,n)} {d \choose k} S(n,k)\tag{2} \label{2}$$
involving [Stirling numbers of the second kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind) $S(n,k)$ which is just the number of partitions of a set with $n$ elements in $k$ different subsets.

*((\ref{2}) is also the number of unitary monomial in $d$ variables of degree $n$ or the number of partial derivatives of order $n$ of a function of $d$ variables.)*

**As a rule, "if one does not see this formula anywhere, it is probably wrong" ... but here is a**

*Proof??: There are*

- *${d \choose 1}$ possible vectors of the form $e_{i}\otimes \cdots \otimes e_{i}$,*
- *${d \choose 2}$ possible choices of a pair $(e_i, e_j)$ of different basis vector. But a basic tensor may "contain" only 1 $e_i$ and the rest of $e_j$, or two $e_i$ and the rest of $e_j$, or three $e_i$ and the rest of $e_j$ etc. Each possibility correspond to a partition of $n$ in two (non trivial) subsets and there are $S(n,2)$ partitions.*
- *${d \choose 3}\times S(n,3)$ possible vectors "containing" exactly three different basis vectors $e_{i}, e_j$ and $e_k$.*
- etc. ... It stops at $k=\min(d,n)$.

*The first equality is given by the usual trick (e.g. Problem 2. p.12 in PDEs (2010) by Lawrence Evans). Consider $d+n-1$ boxes*
$$ \begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
 & & & & & & & & &\\
\hline
\end{array}$$
out of which one chooses $n\ $ (chosen boxes $\bullet$; rest filled with $\vert$)
$$ \begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
 \vert &  \vert& \bullet & \vert & \bullet & \bullet & \vert & \vert & \bullet & \vert \\
\hline
\end{array}$$
$$ \begin{array}{cccccccccccc}
 \vert &  \vert& \bullet & \vert & \bullet & \bullet & \vert & \vert & \bullet & \vert 
\end{array} \tag{3} \label{3}$$
There are of course ${ d+n-1 \choose n}$ possibilities each of which corresponds to a choice of $(i_1, \cdots, i_n),\ 1\leq i_1 \leq i_2 \leq \cdots \leq i_n \leq d $ as in (\ref{1}): each separator, delimiter $\vert$ should be thought as the side of a new sequence of boxes: i.e. (\ref{3}) should be thought as
$$ \begin{array}{cccccccccccccccc}
 1 &\vert & 2 & \vert & \bullet & \vert & \bullet & \bullet & \vert & 5 & \vert & \bullet & \vert & 7
\end{array} \tag{4} \label{4}$$
In this example where $d=7$ and $n=4$, (\ref{4}) corresponds to $(i_1, \cdots, i_4)=(3,4,4,6)$

Comment: The Stirling numbers are for partitioning **distinct** objects into **non-distinct** boxes. For this problem, you are partitioning **non-distinct** objects (which determine how much each basis vectors appears) into **distinct** boxes (the basis vectors, $e_i$ and $e_j$). To correct your formula, you need to replace $S(n,k)$ with $\binom{n-1}{k-1}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The formula 
$$
\sum_{k=1}^{\min(d,n)}\binom{d}k\color{red}{S(n,k)}=\binom{d+n-1}{n}
$$
is incorrect. The correct formula is
$$
\sum_{k=1}^{\min(d,n)}\binom{d}k\color{green}{\binom{n-1}{k-1}}=\binom{d+n-1}{n}
$$
Here is why the second is correct. After choosing which of the $k$ basis vectors will comprise the tensor product $e_{i_1}\otimes \dots\otimes e_{i_k}$, you need to choose the exponents of each factor $e_{i_j}$, that is, how many times each factor is repeated. Each factor must be repeated at least once, and the sum of the multiplicities must equal $n$.

There is a clever way to approach this problem; take a row of $n$ identical dots. There are $n-1$ spaces between adjacent pairs of these dots. Choose $k-1$ of these spaces, and place  a vertical bar in the spaces; this can be done in $\color{green}{\binom{n-1}{k-1}}$ ways. These bars divide the $n$ dots into $k$ consecutive groups. The number of dots in each group represents the multiplicity of each basis vector.

The Stirling numbers do not apply here. $S(n,k)$ counts the number of ways to put $n$ distinct objects into $k$ identical boxes so that each box is nonempty. For this problem, you are putting identical balls into distinct boxes; each box represents one of the basis vectors of $V$, and the number of balls in each box determines the multiplicity of that vector in the tensor product. You can check directly your formula does not work when $d=2$, as
$$
\sum_{k=1}^2\binom{2}kS(n,k)=2\cdot S(n,1)+1\cdot S(n,2)=2\cdot 1+1\cdot (2^{n-1}-1)\neq \binom{2+n-1}{n}=n+1
$$

Comment: I was wondering why I had not seen this identity before. Of course! It's not the Vandermonde Convolution Identity. Lol $\ddot \smile$